# c++ in function- an error for "a reference .. can not be initialized with a value"

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I 'm still confused for my problem after spending an amount of time to digging related posts/online resources.
My sample codes (test.cc) are :

---

```
void testsub(const int* &xx );
int main ()
{
 int* xx;
 xx= new int [10];
 testsub(xx);
 }
 void testsub(const int* & xx){}
```

---

The compiling error message(pgcpp) read

```
"test.cc", line 7: error: a reference of type "const int *&" (not const-qualified)
cannot be initialized with a value of type "int *"
  testsub(xx);
          ^
1 error detected in the compilation of "test.cc"."
```

Why?  Your help is appreciated. 
Best wishes,
Ting

Comment: Do you want testsub to modify the pointer in main?

Comment: @NeilKirk, Originally, I wanted to use const to prevent changes to the xx in the sub.

Comment: You just need `const int *xx`

Comment: @NeilKirk, yes, you are right. That is the "answer" suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
void testsub(const int* xx );
int main ()
{
    int xx [10];
    testsub(xx);
}
void testsub(const int* xx){}
```

You don't need the &, because you are passing a pointer as argument.

Comment: Yes, this does work. Thanks a lot to all of you. After reading your posts, I think I understand this better.  I didn't tell the differences between the pointers and non-pointers as the dummy arguments. Unfortunately I can only choose one answer.

Answer (score 5):

`int*` cannot be used where the argument type is `const int* &`.

Say you have:

```
const int a = 10;

void foo(const int* & ip)
{
   ip = &a;
}

int main()
{
   int* ip = NULL;
   foo(ip);
   *ip = 20;  // If this were allowed, you will be able to
              // indirectly modify the value of "a", which 
              // is not good.
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu, and @Mike, both your explanations are very clear for me to understand why it doesn't work. While the answer I chose directly help me realize my confusion came from omitting the differences between the pointers and non-pointers. So, I chose that as the answer.  All your prompt helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, the argument type is incompatible; the function wants a pointer to `const int`, while you supply a pointer to `int`.

If you're asking why that's incompatible: allowing it would allow you to break const-correctness, as in this example:

```
void testsub(const int* &xx ) {
    static const int x;
    xx = &x;
}

int* xx;
testsub(xx);  // Shouldn't be allowed, because...
*xx = 666;    // BOOM! modifying a constant object.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you forward a "C-Array" (your int[10]), you will have a pointer to the first element of this array in your function.

```
void testsub(const int* xx );
int main ()
{
 int* xx;
 xx= new int [10];
 testsub(xx);
 }
 void testsub(const int* xx){}
```

I think you got confused by your book, because they always write something like "Call by reference". That doesn't mean to pass the parameter as a reference with the &.
Often it is useful to pass also the size of the array to the function ... so it would like:

```
void testsub(const int* xx, size_t arraySize);
int main ()
{
 int* xx;
 xx= new int [10];
 testsub(xx, 10);
 }
 void testsub(const int* xx, size_t arraySize){}
```

Now you can access the array in your function and you have the possibility to check the index, if you want to access the array with an index.

```
void testsub(int* xx, size_t arraySize)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<arraySize; ++i)
  //                    ^ this way you will never try to access
  //                      memory, which does not belong to the array
  //                      => no seg fault, or whatever happens
  {
    // do sth. with the array ... for example setting values to 0
    xx[i] = 0;
  }
}
```